# Why is safari browser not able to play h.264 high10 with pixel format yuv420p10le video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, safari, h.264, ffmpeg-wasm

I have read and found that Safari Supports HDR as well as H264 Codecs.
But When I generate HDR video using h.264 codecs using ffmpeg, the safari gives error in playing the video which chrome is easily able to play.
[Video Error on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP2U6.png)
I am able to play the video with pixel format yuv420p ( 8 bit ).
Is 10 bit video not supported with H264 in Safari?

I used FFMPEG.WASM to generate video with following properties:
-framerate 0.1 -pattern_type glob -i *.png -tag:v avc1 -c:v libx264
-profile:v high10 -crf 20
-sws_flags spline+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_int 
-color_trc smpte2084 -color_primaries bt2020
-color_range pc -colorspace bt2020nc 
-pix_fmt yuv420p10le -vf eq=brightness=0.12 out.mp4"

Comment: Can you share the browser console output also including any errors - this will help people understand the issue.

Comment: @Mick There is no error in browser console. its not working on Safari, but plays on Chrome successfully.